# Comparing buffer with argv error

Tags: linux, character, buffer, argv

I am trying to write a command to replace characters in a file. For example,
**./replace E XY hello.txt**
[b]hello.txt [/b]contains the words [b]HELLO WORLD[/b]. The letter E will be replaced by XY.
Therefore, **HELLO WORLD** will become **HXYLLO WORLD.**
I've read the file to a **char buf[100]**

```
 0   1   2   3   4  5   6   7   8   9   10
[H]-[E]-[L]-[L]-[O]-[]-[W]-[O]-[R]-[L]-[D]
```

I would like to say:

```
If buf[x] == argv[1],
then buf[x] = argv[2]
```

where x is a specific buffer element (in this case buf[1] == argv[1]).

I am getting this error: **assignment makes integer without cast** .

How can I compare the elements in the buffer to the argument vector??

Comment: Your syntax can be fixed to address the type issue, but your algorithm is very incomplete.  You need to iterate over the arguments and add another subscript to argv:  (buf[x] == argv[1][n]) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using C (which seems likely given the error message):

You can't just compare strings that way in C. You're just comparing the pointers now.
You wan to do this:

```
if (! strcmp(buf, argv)) {
  // strings are equal
}
```

You might want to read up on [C string handling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling).

Comment: ok. But the problem is I am trying to replace 'I' with XY. But 'I' only occupies one element.

Comment: Yes. You'll need to do a little more work than just in-place substitution. Try copying the string to a new buffer and scanning for the patterns you want to replace while copying.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a program which replaces strings as described (and much more), try [`streplace`](http://code.google.com/p/streplace/).

If you want to implement this, try it using languages like Java, C++ or Python where string handling is much easier than in C.

If you must use C, you have to use functions like 'strcmp()', 'strcpy()', 'memcpy()' or 'memmove()'.  Hint: the `char buf[100]` might nor be a good choice to read in a whole file.

Edit after comment:
Please think about your concept and design - this is not ok.  Example: with the current solution you miss matches with start in one 'read' block and end in the next.

Also your current program has some problems: IMHO you 'forgot' to close the comment in line 40 which skips the closing bracket which does a mess with the rest of the program.

Please: think before you type!  Make a design first and write it down.

Also please: read (and understand) the original answer (especially the part with the string functions); adapt your program.